# PHP Forgot Password Script

Tags: php, html, authentication, forgot-password

So, I have created a script, one for logon, one for resetting the users password.

Here is the Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Forgot your password?</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
$email=$_POST['email'];
if($_POST['submit']=='Send')
{
mysql_connect('localhost','username','password') or die(mysql_error);
mysql_select_db('softlrdl_testlogon');
$query="select * from users where email='$email'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(error);
if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
echo "User exist";
}
else
{
echo "No user exist with this email id";
}
}
?>
<?php
mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters)
if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
$code=rand(100,999);
$message="Your activation link is: http://forgot.site.com/forgot.php?email=$email&code=$code
mail($email, "Password Reset Link", $message);
echo "Email sent";
}
else
{
echo "No user exist with this email id";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home/softlrdl/public_html/forgot/forgot.php on line 28
```

And I don't know what is causing it...

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: missing semicolon after `mail()` function

Comment: YOu should copy your code into dreamviewer, which will show you the syntax errors in red. It will help you find the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a semicolon here, but also there are not any variables assigned to them. You better need to assign variables to them. But i think you forgot that there, if not, you need to edit them like below:

```
$to = "to@mail.com";
$subject = "yoursubject";
$message = "yourmessage";
$headers = "yourheaders";
$parameters = "yourparameters";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,$parameters);
```

Also here you forgot double quotes and semicolon too again.

```
$message= "Your activation link is: http://forgot.site.com/forgot.php?email=$email&code=$code";
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing semicolon ; after mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters)

Comment: Also to,subject,message,headers,parameters need to have $ sign for each one. Besides, I don't see you assign value for these variables yet

Answer (score 0):

You have a few syntax errors:

1. You forgot the semicolon at `mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters)`
2. You forgot the ending `"` and `;` at `$message="Your activation link is: http://forgot.site.com/forgot.php?email=$email&code=$code`
3. You never actually set `mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters)` any of these fields